# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{\sec ^2 (x)} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \sqrt{\sec^2 (x)} dx$

But I have no idea where to start. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Maybe, first figure out what $\sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ is?

Comment: Well, as far as i can get is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{cos ^2(x)}}$. That unfortunately gets me nowhere

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$ for any $u\in\mathbb R$. Since $\sec(x) \in (0,2]$ for all $x\in(0,{\pi\over3})$, you know that $\sqrt{\sec^2(x)} = |\sec(x)| = \sec(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sec{x}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sec{x}(\sec{x}+\tan{x})}{\sec{x}+\tan{x}}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\sec^2{x}+\sec{x}\tan{x}}{\tan{x}+\sec{x}}dx$$
$$=\Big[\log{(\sec{x}+\tan{x})}\Big]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$$
$$=\log{(2+\sqrt{3})}$$

Answer (score 1):

As on the integration interval, $\sec x>0$, we may simplify to
$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi3\sec x\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\tfrac\pi3\frac{\mathrm dx}{\cos x}=\int_0^\tfrac\pi3\frac{\cos x\,\mathrm dx}{\cos^2 x}.$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Find the interval(s) where $\sec(x)$ is positive vs. negative in $[0,\pi/3].$ then you can get rid of the absolute values (inserting $-$ if negative) and integrate $\sec(x)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is positive on my interval, so i just skip the absolute value, right?

Comment: Yes, if sure it's positive, can just integrate $\sec(x)$ [since $\sqrt(A^2)=|A|,$ which is $A$ if you know $A>0.$